# Can I launch app on one emulator and mobile browser in another emulator in the same test?

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

I have a use case where I need to copy a link from an app installed in emulator 1, close the app, switch to emulator 2 and then launch browser on emulator 2 and paste the link copied from app in emulator 1. How can I achieve this? The code I wrote invokes the browser in emulator 1 itself and pastes the link.

```
    File app = new File("abcd.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5554");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "100");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());

    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    /*
     String link = code to get the link
    */
    driver.closeApp();
    driver.quit();


    DesiredCapabilities cap1 = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5556");
    cap1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
    cap1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "chrome");
    cap1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "7.0");

    WebDriver webdriver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap1);  // chrome mobile
    webdriver.get(link);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to you need to put Device **udid** in the **DesiredCapabilities**. To find the device udid of your emulator, use can use **adb devices** in the command prompt. It will show the device udid.

Then you can copy the device udid and add it in the DesiredCapabilities.

```
//Other desired capabilities
cap.setCapability("udid","your emulator 1 device udid");
AppiumDriver driver= new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
```

It will launch your app in the emulator 1. Now you can copy the link from the device one using

```
String myLink= driver.findElementById("elements id here").getText();
```

Then add **udid** of the emulator2 in the **DesiredCapabilities cap1**

```
//other desired capabilities
cap1.setCapability("udid", "emulator 2 udid");

AppiumDriver driver2 = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

//open URL in chrome browser
driver.get(myLink);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Works perfect !!